# Solving PDE via change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving the following PDE , using change of variables . If anyone could help it'd be a lot appreciated .

> $$\begin{cases}
> (x-y)u_{y}-xu_{x}+u = x^{2}+1 &   \\ 
>  u(x,0) = x^{2}-1&  
> \end{cases}$$

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello @Aryadeva , what I found in my lecture ,  I wrote : $\xi = x + \alpha y$ , and $\eta = \beta x + y$ , then writing $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\eta$ and $\xi$

Comment: This is what I get : $x = \frac{\alpha \eta - \xi}{\alpha \beta - 1}$
$y = \frac{\beta \xi - \eta}{\alpha \beta - 1}$ , then in the example the teacher used the chain rule , but I didn't get what comes next so if you can help ..

Comment: He also say that we can use $\eta(x,y)=x$ I don't see exactly why

Comment: I checked but that change of variable you are given dosent seem to work..

Comment: There was a mistake , it was $\eta = x^{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
(x-y)u_{y}-xu_{x}+u = x^{2}+1 &   \\ 
 u(x,0) = x^{2}-1&  
\end{cases}$$
Thanks to the method of characteristics it is easy to find the solution :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=1-x^2+2x^2e^{y/x}-2e^{-y/x}}$$
This suggests the change of variables :
$\quad \begin{cases}
\xi=x^2\\
\eta=e^{y/x}
\end{cases}$

But I admit that it was difficult to guess this change of variables at first, without the preliminary calculus. Moreover, even with this suggested change of variables the calculus remains not easy. I am therefore a little doubtful about the interest of the method of change of variables in the present case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

With the variables change

$$
\cases{
a=x\ln x + y\\
b= x
}
$$

we have $u(x,y) = v(a,b)$ and

$$
a v_a(a,b) + b v_b(a,b) -v(a,b)+b^2+1=0
$$

The homogeneous

$$
a v_a(a,b) + b v_b(a,b) -v(a,b) = 0
$$

has the solution.

$$
v_h(a,b) = a\Phi\left(\frac ab\right)
$$

Comment: Hello @Ceasareo , I don't understand how you get $a = x\ln{x}+y$

Comment: Analyzing the characteristic's method for the homogeneous.